# Render prop as a component to prevent change in the order of hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am wrapping every routed page in a top level component but the passed in `page` is a function (for reasons I cannot export components as is) so, in order to render them, I have to call their functions directly like so:

```
const RoutePageContainer = ({ title, page }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {title && <h3 className={styles.title}>{title}</h3>}
      <div className={styles.page}>{page()}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This worked up until some point but now I am getting `Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks` errors, which I believe is caused by this function call here, so I am trying to fix it.

[Kent C. Dodds's blog post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component) describes the problem and how to fix it but I am not sure how I can render this page prop as a JSX element because it is dynamic. Passing it as a children prop also won't work. Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: We can't reproduce your issue based on this piece of code. This is just a stateless function component. Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an element with `React.createElement` seems to be doing the trick.

```
const RoutePageContainer = ({ title, page }) => {
  const Page = React.createElement(page, null, null);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {title && <h3 className={styles.title}>{title}</h3>}
      <div className={styles.page}>{Page}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```